# Where to find all possible errors from (python)selenium and their webdrivers?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running python-selenium tests and depending on the configuration, the used browser, the used webdriver, the time of the day or whatever I always get very different error messages displayed. It looks, as if the error message are randomly selected.

Some examples:

```
Can not connect to the Service chromedriver
session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed
DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.875
unknown error: cannot activate web view
invalid argument: invalid locator
chrome not reachable
```

I am looking for a comprehensive list of all such possible selenium/webdriver errors, and their immediate cause, and what could be the realistic cause.

I mean, somewhere in the code there must be a line something like:

```
if <something>:
    raise(<incomprehensive and confusing error message>)
```

A table, a list that lists all of these errors and explains what is the immediate cause (like the reason in the if statement), and what is the user-facing cause (what did the user do wrong, or the environment, or whatever) what caused that error, and how this error could be possible fixed.

Where can I find such a comprehensive error list?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://www.guru99.com/exception-handling-selenium.html) mate?

Comment: A good start, but my example error messages do not seem to appear in your list

Comment: oh k can you try running in headless mode and just check? It may be issue with XVFB or x virtual frame buffer .. im not at all sure . .

Comment: I want a (if possible) complete list of possible errors. This is my question. I do not want to solve a specific issue. I am just asking for a list of possible errors